# How to handle read() first with spring integration TCP outbound gateway

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm implementing a tcp client which will send request to a server and expect an response. But when the client 1st connect to the server, the server will send a hello msg, with tcp outbound gateway, it expects to send then receive. How can I do receive (only when first connect) then do my usually send and receive logic? And if I need to keep the connection alive, is there a way to send keep alive msg to the same connection by some scheduling task?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a gateway use [Collaborating Channel Adapters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#d4e10831) for completely async operations.

> Collaborating adapters can also be used (server-side or client-side) for totally asynchronous communication (rather than with request/reply semantics).

You can use operating system keep alives (`SO_KEEPALIVE`). Or you can roll your own application-level keep alives with a polled inbound channel adapter...

```
<int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="toTcp" expression="'foo'">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="60000" />
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Comment: Hi Gary, still a little bit unclear on the correlation. Currently, we preceded the length of the request (1st 4 bytes) and sent it to the server. There is no data in the body I can use as the correlation id. I looked at the multiplex example, but that requires to send the correlation id and the server returns back the id which we can't do. Server will just reject the request since it is invalid req format.

Comment: Hmmm... if you don't need truly async operations but simply get this "hello" message (and then go into a normal request/reply scenario, I think your only choice will be to add an interceptor to handle the hello... http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#ip-interceptors

Comment: is there a way I can manually read the socket inside the interceptor send(Message<?> message) so I can discard the hello msg before sending the 1st request?

Comment: You don't "read the socket", but just subclass `TcpConnectionInterceptorSupport`, override `onMessage()`; if it's the hello message, discard it (or log it, or do whatever you want), for all other messages (replies) call `super.OnMessage()` and it will go to the gateway as a reply to a request.